# HeadphoneFence.unplugged in the Google Awareness API fires regardless of the state

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness

I am using a Nexus 5X phone and trying out the Google Awareness API HeadphoneFence.unplugged() https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/HeadphoneFence

I found that it fires my pending intent when the fence is first added, then no matter I plug in or unplug the headphone, it fires up even it supposes to only fire for unplugging.

My code is not that interest since it's straight out from the guide.

```
Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
                                getGoogleApiClient(),
                                new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                                        .addFence(
                                                "something",
                                                HeadphoneFence.unplugging();,
                                                createSendHeadphoneUnpluggedMessagePendingIntent(context))
                                        .build())
                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                        if(status.isSuccess()) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "Headphone unplugged fence was successfully registered.");
                                        } else {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Headphone unplugged fence could not be registered: " + status);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code? I will try to replicate it

Comment: Forgot to tag you for the reply ^^

Comment: Put in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SYfuit10 Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What about the Callbacks? i.e the https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-callbacks stuff, I can't manage to get any callbacks to fire. I only see the states when I queryFence()

Comment: That part is a bit confusing. Since the API allows for a pending intent, you don't really need an additional callback for that. In my code, my pendingintent wraps an intent that calls BackgroundOneshotService, which basically just prints a message and exits, that's how I know the fence fires when I register the fence, and when I unplug or plug in the headphone.

Comment: Yeah I can't even get it to fire in my setup, will try more tonight when I have some free time

Comment: can this API  detect  the headphones state(plugged, unplugged) even if the application is not launched or it must be launchhed ???

Answer (score 0):

@Herman It indeed seems thats how it behaves. It gives you the state of the headphones when the application is launched, (when fence / receiver is registered) and also when you plug/unplug them.

It makes sense in a way I guess, that if the headphones are connected, you are not unplugging them, hence it fires FenceState.FALSE and when you unplug them, it fires FenceState.TRUE. However you may choose to act upon the desired event in the

```
switch (fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                case FenceState.TRUE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fence > Headphones plugged out");
                    break;
                case FenceState.FALSE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fence > Headphones are NOT plugged out.");
                    break;
                case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fence > The headphone fence is in an unknown state.");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: The problem is that if I want to send out a toast like "you just unplugged your phone!", that cannot be done without me keeping track of what I have checked before. It does not comply to the notion of fence, notify you when something happens. If the behavior should be what you described, then what's the point of another fence: HeadphoneFence.pluggingIn()? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/HeadphoneFence

Comment: @Herman Well the FenceQuery method provides the previous state, so if that is of any help you can use that, but I get and agree with your point

Comment: I just found that querying FenceState is not as bad as I thought. FenceState.TRUE does not mean the headphone is unplugged. It actually means the headphone is unplugging. FenceState.FALSE means it's not unplugging. That's why when the fence is registered, the fence state is FenceState.FALSE no matter the headphone is plugged or unplugged at that point. Simply speaking, I just need to query the state to make sure it's FenceState.TRUE to send out the "unplugging" message. I don't need to store the previous state, etc.